# How can I keep my cursor from locking on in Lord of the Rings Online?

Tags: lord-of-the-rings-online

When I'm playing Lord of the Rings Online I've come across something pretty annoying: whenever I right click on an NPC to speak to them or right click on a quest item to collect it, etc. my cursor stays locked on even after I've finished speaking with them or collected said quest item. The frustrating part is that when I walk away my camera is turned to focus on that thing leaving me to have to spin the camera around just to face forward, even though I'm finished interacting with whatever it was.

It is pretty annoying having to press ESC or click off of that item just to keep my camera from facing it while I'm trying to walk away. I know pressing ESC is a pretty simple fix and it's kind of juvenile for me to complain about something so easily "fixed" but is there any other way to prevent this from happening? Anything in the menus that will automatically take my selection off of whatever it is I just interacted with once I'm finished?

The main reason I'm annoyed by it is because it happens even when I right click something just to interact. I could understand if it happened when I left clicked because obviously I selected it, but when you just want to open a shop menu with an NPC or collect a quest item by a brief right click, it becomes a nuisance, especially on collect quests when I'm constantly having to press ESC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I once had the same issue. You must have clicked X key (a camera mode shortcut).

Click it again to leave that camera option.

(The best way to solve your problems in game is asking in global chat. There are many players who can help you)

Comment: Awesome thanks! That actually seems like it might be my issue, I remember pressing x and a couple other keys nearby just to see what they did.